# Can you use your action to take a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, actions, bonus-action

During a game tonight, I had a DM state using an action to do a bonus action is allowed by RAW. I was always taught this is not the case. I understand it's the DM's table, but for my own knowledge for my own table, is that correct?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.

Comment: Historical note: You could do this in D&D 4th edition, which lets you perform a minor action in place of a standard action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bonus Actions are *in addition* to the normal action

This is described on page 189 PHB:

> On your turn, you can **move** a distance up to your speed and **take one action**. (...) 
> Various class features, spells, and other abilities let you take an **additional action** on your turn called a bonus action. (...) You choose when to take a bonus action during your turn, unless the bonus action’s timing is specified, and anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions also prevents you from taking a bonus action.

So, you normally can only take a bonus action when you would be able to take your action -- that may be what your DM had in mind. But the bonus action is always an *additional* action, it is never a replacement instead of your normal action.

You cannot take two bonus actions by using your action and your bonus action, because the bonus action text explicitly says:

> You can take a bonus action only when a special ability, spell, or other feature of the game states that you can do something as a bonus action. You otherwise don’t have a bonus action to take.
> You can take **only one bonus action on your turn**, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

Comment: This answer showed up in the LQP queue so I’m marking it “Looks OK” because it is correct and well cited.

Answer (score 7):

The official ruling is that bonus actions and actions are not interchangeable, as per a [Sage Advice Compendium entry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA116) on the topic:

> **Can a bonus action be used as an action or vice versa? For example, can a bard use a bonus action to grant a Bardic Inspiration die and an action to cast *healing word*?**
>
> No. Actions and bonus actions aren’t interchangeable. In the example, the bard could use Bardic Inspiration or *healing word* on a turn, not both.

As Groody's answer also indicates, this is backed up in the RAW by the [bonus action section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions) of the combat rules indicating you only get one bonus action on your turn:

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.